# Getting "integer expression expected" and I can't see why

Tags: bash, shell-script

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
for (( i=0; i<=10; i++  ))
 do 
if [ "$i" -eq 3 ] || [ "$1" -eq 7 ]
 then
continue
fi
  echo "$i"
done
```

When running this, I get

```
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
0
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
1
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
2
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
4
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
5
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
6
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
7
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
8
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
9
file: line 4: [: : integer expression expected
10
```

... and I don't understand why.

Comment: You may need to choose a different font for your terminal and/or editor.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 8):

If you are invoking the script with no argument, the command:

```
[ "$1" -eq 7 ]
```

will evaluate to:

```
[ "" -eq 7 ]
```

which is an error, as `-eq` is a numerical operator: it needs two integers as operands; an empty string is not an integer.

If you are not expecting to invoke the script with an argument and instead are wishing to compare the value of `i` to `7`, you probably want:

```
[ "$i" -eq 7 ]
```

rather than:

```
[ "$1" -eq 7 ]
```